# What character is Mio's doll from?

Tags: k-on

In K-ON!, Ritsu found a doll (belonging to Mio) of an old man who's almost bald with a huge nose.

If I'm not mistaken, it was shown when they were cleaning their club room.

[image]
(season 2, episode 2, 4:54)

Who is that old man doll? Was that doll based from a real person or from another anime or just a random creation from K-ON! itself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This](http://yuaayua.blog112.fc2.com/blog-entry-246.html) Japanese blog says it's a plush of "ウゴウゴルーガ" (Ugo Ugo Ru-ga).

I'm personally not familiar with the show, but the it strongly resembles おやじむし (Oyajimushi), which I think is an "insect father"? Whatever that means.

Searching further, [this](http://cyobin.blog10.fc2.com/blog-entry-1552.html) blog and [this](http://plaza.rakuten.co.jp/shirakawakaido/diary/201003220000/) site agree.

[Here](http://blogc.fujitv.co.jp/simg/blogimg/9aab7/90025/52663_pcl.jpg)'s a picture of a plush doll that looks virtually identical, except for the nose being quite a bit longer.

And [here](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%E3%81%8A%E3%82%84%E3%81%98%E3%82%80%E3%81%97%20%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B4%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AC&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch)'s a Google search with multiple images for "おやじむし ウゴウゴルーガ" (Oyajimushi Ugo Ugo Ru-ga).

Among the images, there is one image from Amazon showing the manga where this character originates from:

[image]

The manga is titled [**おやじむしの人生 (人生いろいろウゴウゴ・ルーガ)**](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%81%8A%E3%82%84%E3%81%98%E3%82%80%E3%81%97%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%BA%E7%94%9F-%E4%BA%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B4%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B4%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AC-%E7%94%B0%E4%B8%AD-%E7%A7%80%E5%B9%B8/dp/4938704315).

Comment: Good catch! And great answer!